# What caused all my chain links to become stiff after a month in a tent despite having been cleaned and lubed beforehand?

Tags: chain, winter, rust

I've left my winter road bike outside in a bike tent for about a month (winter, UK). I noticed that pretty much all links are stiff and the chain is slightly rusted, making it impossible to use. Some rust was also present on the cassette.

My question is, what caused this and how can I prevent this from happening again? The chain was cleaned with degreaser and lubed after my last ride, and the tent is pretty good (as in water doesn't get in).

Comment: By "bike tent" I presume its an unsealed cover over the bike that is tied off to itself?   IE, without a floor ?  A photo might help, but at the moment it sounds like a fancy tarpaulin over the bike.

Comment: It does have a floor. It's effectively like a normal tent but shaped to fit a couple of bikes

Comment: "how can I prevent this from happening again?" Keep it beside you in your bed when you're not riding it, and stare at it obsessively.  Rust can't form while you are staring.

Comment: @kloddant My knife begs to differ. But I have a really high prescription so maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even though there may not have been direct contact with water, there is water in the air. In a tent, the constant cycle of heating and cooling through the day and night, and the relative differences in the temperature of the metal and the air can cause condensation to form on the metal and subsequent rust. This can happen to bicycles in a garage as well, but there is typically less variation in the ambient and relative temperatures due to higher insulation.

What I do if I am not going to be riding my bike for an extended period is:

- Clean everything;
- Lube the chain with a wet lube - this will attract dust but will repel water;
- Use a spray lube to lightly coat the cassette and chain rings.

When bringing my bike out of storage, there is another cycle of cleaning to remove the heavier wet lube and replace it with my normal dry or wax lube.

Answer (score 13):

As you know living in the UK, we are an island that is prone to high humidity and damp overcast weather.  When left outside anything that is remotely damp (you cleaned your chain and its virtually impossible to get it properly dry in winter) will remain damp until spring.
Something like a bike tent will have poor air flow and trap moisture inside making this situation worse.

This is one reason why the 'winter' bike is popular here in the UK - people don't want to expose their best bike to the elements.

A few options that I have found to work are:

1. Keeping the bike inside where its warm and dry (I guess a temperature controlled garage would work here too).
2. Using a large quantity of wet lube. Chain lube is not really supposed to coat the outer surface of the chain, but by using a large quantity of a heavy/wet lube you can create a protective layer.  Note that this quickly turns into a black sticky mess and causes increased wear rate - but no rust.
3. Rust proof chains - in recent years i've been using a single speed mountain bike with a rustproof chain. It works much better than I expected.  I'm not sure if this type of chain is available for geared bikes.

Comment: Even a non-heated but built-in (so it gets a little bit of heat from the house) and insulated garage helps a lot

Comment: Unfortunately keeping it in a garage or the house is not an option for me. I'll try the wet lube option and also ride it more often 

Answer (score 6):

You don't say if you did anything to work the oil (wet lube) into the chain.

If you use 1 drop per roller you really need to spin the pedals quite a few times to spread the oil out, especially if you've just washed it.  Between washing and oiling I try to get as much water out as possible by spinning the pedals and by dropping the back wheel onto the ground, but there's definitely still some in there.

For planned, prolonged winter storage, I'd clean and oil, then a day or so later wipe the chain down and oil again.  Ideally it would get a short ride in the dry on non-salted roads in between.

Comment: I normally spin backwards a few times and clean the oil off the following day (without re-applying). I should probably put more effort in drying the chain before applying the oil

Comment: The problem is you can't get it really dry.  A couple of repeats of spinning and wiping with a dry cloth are about the best you'll do

Comment: Compressed air blasts can work to get water out. But canned air gets pricey and a compressor costs money.

Comment: Couldn't compressed air forcefully push dirt to places where it can be harmful? Of course, shouldn't be a problem after proper cleaning.

Answer (score 2):

If your tent is reasonably tight then you might try to add some dehumidifying agent. Around where I live you can get those cheaply and they slowly absorb up to 500 ml from the ambient air. This might be enough to prevent condensation on your bike. The tighter and smaller the tent the better.

**EDIT**
The question arose whether the desiccant would be sufficient in damp UK winter. The answer is yes. One cubic meter of air contains about 8g of water when fully saturated at 8°C. Assuming rather spacious 5 m³ for the tent, the 500ml dehumidifying container would be able to remove the entire moisture from the air about 12 times. This number drops to about 3.5 when we put the bike into the tent at 30°C in fully saturated air. We should also keep in mind that desiccant will usually not remove all moisture from ambient air (and that is not required to prevent rust). So even with significant leakage in the tent one simple dehumidifying container capable of absorbing 500ml of water from the air should be sufficient.

**EDIT2**
If worried about too much ingress of fresh moisture into the bike tent, then one can easily check the filling of the desiccant after a week. After initial removal of most moisture (including water drops left on the bike) the ingress of fresh moisture through leaks of the bike tent should be fairly constant, so that extrapolation should be feasible.
Additional benefit of this method: It potentially protects all components susceptible to rust, not just the oiled chain and related components. I had screws on my handle bar starting to rust during the first rainy season (continued to ride the bike through the rain and not much option to dry it).

Comment: Is that really enough to absorb significant amounts of moisture from a damp, dreary, UK winter? OP doesn't indicate how big the tent is, but even a small, bike-sized tent is a fairly large volume of space to attempt to dehumidify with a desiccant.

Comment: Positioning the shelter somewhere that it is in sunlight during the day would be helpful.  Presumes there is some sunlight though.

Comment: Volatile corrosion inhibitor might work better. But you might need two or three blocks depending on the tent size.

Comment: @Criggie Not really. The assumption is that the tent is sufficiently tight, so a change of temperature would not change the amount of water inside the tent. Plus, changing the temperature due to sunlight does not change the amount of water in the air anyways, it only changes the relative humidity. Lower relative humidity helps objects dry, but it won't remove moisture from the tent even if it is not sealed.

Comment: The movement of air though a tent like structure is impossible to prevent. Movement in the wind causes a pumping action though holes, zips etc,. Additionally, few fabrics are really impervious to water vapor molecules, as soon as you remove moisture, vapor will make its way through the fabric.  As such, I would be very surprised if dehumidifying the inside of the tent is a practical solution.

Comment: It is described as a bike tent, so I assume some purpose made structure. So I guess it has fabric all around and the only openings would be the zippers to close it. Of course there will be ingress of additional moisture, but since there is no pressure gradient this will be rather slow. Equilibration of differences of partial pressure of water is rather slow, especially when obstructed by barriers.

Comment: @laolux the things I've seen called bike tents have often been open at the bottom, so water can get underneath, or vapour can rise from the soil. I've just looked and one clearly has vents while another specifies a "mesh groundsheet".  If it's s repurposed sleeping tent, those are always ventilated. Then you put a wet bike in there once or twice and overwhelm the desiccant.  Even if sealed, you can assume a complete air change every time it's opened, which could easily be twice a day.  Sorry, but this is never going to work.  Your calculations are correct but don't cover the whole situation

Comment: So a slightly reluctant -1 from me.  Where dessicant could work is if the bike was sealed away for the season, dry to start with.  If the OP used a bike-sized plastic bag and taped it up tight (I have one, never used it) you might offer a solution, but not with a tent

Comment: @ChrisH The way I understand the question is that the OP put the bike in the bike tent and left it there for a whole month and then was surprised that the chain was rusty when OP got the bike out again. So it is not a daily use situation, but a storage solution. Also, the OP calls the tent pretty pretty good (water doesn't get in) and in the comments specifically says that the tent does have floor. Of course, nothing mentioned about the tightness of the floor, but given that water does not get into the tent I assume that includes rain water which might come from the bottom. So pretty tight.

Comment: It's probably [this one from Halfords](https://www.halfords.com/cycling/bike-storage-solutions/halfords-3-bike-storage-tent-344259.html) with a great big vent visible at the back to let vapour in as well as out.  As well as the zip.  My "daily" was worst case but you'd be changing the dessicant every few days due to vapour getting in, plus once as the bike dries out.  I've used those disposable ones in a caravan (with all vents taped up) so I know how  quickly they fill up in confined space.

Comment: That looks nice. The vent can be covered easily. Volume and especially surface area is significantly lower than for a caravan. So I think it's worth a try. Especially given the fact that it is easy to check if the method works without having to wait until rust develops. Simply check the status of the desiccant after a reasonable amount of time. The air exchange during the check is unlikely to be relevant, given my above calculation.